# Increment columns in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, increment

Is there a way to increment more than one column in laravel?

Let's say:

```
DB::table('my_table')
->where('rowID', 1)
->increment('column1', 2)
->increment('column2', 10)
->increment('column3', 13)
->increment('column4', 5);
```

But this results to:

`Call to a member function increment() on integer`

I just want to find an efficient way to do this using the given functions from laravel. Thanks. Any suggestions will do.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is no existing function to do this. You have to use `update()`:

```
DB::table('my_table')
   ->where('rowID', 1)
   ->update([
       'column1' => DB::raw('column1 + 2'),
       'column2' => DB::raw('column2 + 10'),
       'column3' => DB::raw('column3 + 13'),
       'column4' => DB::raw('column4 + 5'),
   ]);
```

Comment: hello @lukasgeiter,  what if i have something like this : increment('orders.price', 7/$count, ['orders.amount_paid' => 'John']); where $count is a defined variable. How can i proceed? I am trying to add 7 when incremented

Answer (score 34):

**Increments and Decrements in Laravel Eloquent Model**

Add to cart option is one of the most important functions in e-commerce websites. The tricky part is getting the number of items in the cart to display on the cart icon. The predominant approach to get this done is using the increment and decrement function on Laravel. This also facilitates the addition or removal of a product from your cart. The way to implement this function is ,

```
$user = User::find(‘517c43667db388101e00000f’);
$user->cart_count++;
// $user->cart_count--; // for decrement the count
$user->save()
```

An alternate and easier way is,

```
$user = User::find($article_id);
$user->increment('cart_count');
```

Also these will work:

```
$user->increment('cart_count');// increase one count
$user->decrement('cart_count'); // decrease one count
$user->increment('cart_count',10); // increase 10 count
$user->decrement('cart_count',10); // decrease 10 count
```

Answer (score 13):

Now in laravel 5.7 [laravel query builder, increment and decrement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#increment-and-decrement), it can be done easily.

```
Model::where('id', "rowID")->increment('columne1');`
```

or you can use DB

```
DB::table("my_table")->where('id', "rowID")->increment('column1');
```

Answer (score 10):

For future reference in 5.2 it has been made do able by doing the following

*You may also specify additional columns to update during the operation:*

```
DB::table('users')->increment('votes', 1, ['name' => 'John']);
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#updates

Answer (score 8):

First off, the result of `increment` is an integer according to the documentation: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

So you would have to do a call for each increment:

```
DB::table('my_table')
->where('rowID', 1)
->increment('column1', 2);
DB::table('my_table')
->where('rowID', 1)
->increment('column2', 10);
DB::table('my_table')
->where('rowID', 1)
->increment('column3', 13);
DB::table('my_table')
->where('rowID', 1)
->increment('column4', 5);
```

I'm unable to find any quicker solution, unless you want to solve it with a raw update query command.

Also your example code will probably generate an error as you've closed the statement with `;` and continue with a new `->increment` call on the next line.

Comment: hi, thanks for your fast reponse. but is this efficient? since you call it 4 times? sorry i edited my post about that extra semi-colon

Comment: No, see my update; a raw update command is more efficient.. The question is do you consider this as a solution or not.

Comment: ya i consider it, but maybe any other solution which i can run it once.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of 9.x, you can increment and decrement multiple columns using `incrementEach` and `decrementEach` methods:

```
DB::table('users')->incrementEach([
    'votes' => 5,
    'balance' => 100,
]);
```

(taken from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#increment-and-decrement))

Answer (score 1):

```
$id=5;
$votes=20;
DB::table('users')
   ->where('id', $id)
   ->update([
       'votes' => DB::raw('votes + '.$votes)
]);
```

Comment: could you append your answer with some commentary so that we could better understand your code?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

just use this code

```
\App\Models\User::find(1)->increment('column1');  //id = 1
```

or multi recorded

```
\App\Models\User::where('column1','>','100')->increment('column1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::where('id', "rowID")->increment('columne1');
```

This works for me