# Insert and update count in MySQL Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table like this:

```
User (user_id, count)
```

Now I want to insert a user id to this table, then update count = count + 1. How I can do this in eloquent?

I tried:

```
protected $table = 'user';


    public function insertAndUpdateCount($user_id)
    {
        return $this->insert($user_id)
                    ->increment('count', 1);
    }
```

But it's seem not working.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to use Increment & Decrement?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#increment-and-decrement

Like this

```php
DB::table('users')->increment('votes', 5);
```

Comment: yeah I know! But I want to insert user_id and increment count at same time

Comment: Got it, take a look in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816123/increment-columns-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you set the `count` column to `autoincrement`. Therefore, every time you insert a new row, the value automatically increases by 1. You can do this in a Laravel migration like this: `$table->integer('count', true)` Read more about Laravel Migrations here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations

Out of curiosity: Why do you need a `count` column in the first place? If you just what to get the number of rows at some time, maybe it would be better to use `SELECT COUNT()` at this point. Because with a dedicated `count` column, you not only waste memory, but it also is prone to error, because if you delete a row, the `count` value of the other rows won't change.